# How to calculate inverse of an element using MPC and secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

Suppose we have multiple parties ${P_i}$ each holding a secret share $(y_i,k_i)$ of the secret $(y,k)$. How can we calculate the inverse value $(y+k)^{-1}$ using multiparty computation such that these secret shares are never revealed?

Answer (score 3):

First, to simplify notation, note that computing $(y+k)^{-1}$ is equivalent to computing $z^{-1}$, where $z=y+k$, which can be locally computed by the parties. Furthermore, I assume that $z \in \mathbb{F}_p$ is a field element (e.g., integers mod $p$).

Now, to compute $z^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p$, each party can (locally) sample a random share of a value $r \in \mathbb{F}_p \setminus \{0\}$. Then, the parties reveal $zr$ to compute $(zr)^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p$, in the clear. Finally, the parties use their shares of $r$ to engage in a MPC protocol for multiplication to compute $(zr)^{-1}\cdot r = z^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}_p$. A similar protocol was described in  [Algorithm for computing modular inverse in MPC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63758/algorithm-for-computing-modular-inverse-in-mpc) under a different context.

Comment: You seem to have made quite a few assumptions about the secret sharing scheme

Comment: My answer would probably have worked better as a comment. The main assumption is that @KanchanBisht is using an additive secret sharing scheme over a field, which appears reasonable based on how the question was formulated.

Comment: To clarify, I think your answer is good. I was just (clumsily) pointing out it would be better to explicitly mention you were assuming additivity (especially since you swept under the rug where that property is used: "which can be locally computed by the parties").